# SQL Server - Trusted connection works yet standard security fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server instance via a .NET Winforms client. When I use a "Trusted connection" connection string all works fine, yet when I use a standard security connection string I get an error that the login fails.

The really confusing thing is that in the database both the Windows authentication user and the SQL Server authentication user have the exact same permissions. For testing I made both part of the "sysadmin" role.

I have got to be missing something simple but I have checked username and password over and over yet it still fails. Has anyone else run into this?

**This works ...**

```
string connectionString = @"server=dbserver.myhost.com\myinstance;database=MyDB;integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

**This does not work ...**

```
string connectionString = @"server=dbserver.myhost.com\myinstance;database=MyDB;User Id=testuser;Password=mypassword;";
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your SQL server is configured to accept `mixed authentication mode`

Comment: Check using ODBC connection wizard, whether you are able to connect or not.Prior to this make sure Mixed authentication enabled and user is created and associated with MyDB.